# search box to be aligned in center

Tags: visualforce, search

I want to improve the design of my page.The search box needs to be aligned in center, Tasks title is appearing two times and fields gets displayed when the page loads which should not be.Image attached. Thanks in advance.

```
  <apex:page controller="PagingTasksController">
   <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Tasks" id="pgBlock">

      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
           <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" id="saveButton" value="Save"/>
           <apex:commandButton onclick="resetInlineEdit()" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel"/>
       </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton"
                hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick"
                changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
   <apex:inputText id="searchBox" value="{!searchText}"/>

 <apex:commandButton value="Search" reRender="pgTable,pgBlock" action="{!findTasks}"> </apex:commandButton>

  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Tasks}" var="tsk" id="pgTable">
   </apex:pageBlockTable>

      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!Previous}" rerender="pgTable,pgBlock"
                                status="status" disabled="{!DisablePrevious}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!Next}" reRender="pgTable,pgBlock"
                                status="status" disabled="{!DisableNext}" />
            <apex:actionStatus id="status" startText="Please Wait..."/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
 <apex:enhancedlist type="Activity" height="800" rowsPerPage="50" customizable="False"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div align="center">  ur search box code here </div>
```

to display search box in middle u can use it

Comment: But it is not displaying me at the center? Also fields get displayed when the page first loads?

Comment: hi james i edited my code now just use it u can see search box in middle

Comment: It is working. And as i said,want to improve the design,how do i hide the fields which are showing when the page loads ? And "Tasks" title appears two times, how to remove that and make one title ? Thanks again.

Comment: Since your problem statement was about the search box alignment, this was the answer you got. I suggest marking this as answer and asking new question to address the multiple Tasks label and conditional rendering; the forum isn't really set up to address multiple problems with a single post